# Как сравнить значение в столбцах DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, lambda, dataframe

У меня вот такой DataFrame:

```
ID    Jun   Feb  Mar  Apr  May  Jun
0     170   170  Nan  Nan  Nan  Nan
1     Nan   Nan  Nan  Nan  Nan  Nan 
2     17    17   17   17   17   17
3     Nan   Nan  Nan  2    2    2
4     4     5    5    5    5    5
```

Нужно сравнить значения в столбцах и если они не равны у одного ID то вывести False, а если равно True. Значением Nan можно пренебречь - это отсутствие данных.

Я пробовала делать это через apply

```
df.apply(lambda row: all(i in row.Jun for i in row.Feb), axis=1)
```

Не работает. Есть у кого идеи, как это сделать?

Answer (score 1):

```
In [346]: x = df.set_index('ID').ffill(axis=1).bfill(axis=1)

In [347]: x
Out[347]:
    Jun  Feb  Mar  Apr  May Jun.1
ID
0   170  170  170  170  170   170
1   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN
2    17   17   17   17   17    17
3     2    2    2    2    2     2
4     4    5    5    5    5     5

In [348]: x.eq(x.iloc[:, 0], axis=0).all(axis=1) | x.isnull().all(axis=1)
Out[348]:
ID
0     True
1     True
2     True
3     True
4    False
dtype: bool
```